# Task editor dialog for task scheduler 2.0

Tags: c++, scheduled-tasks

I am working on a legacy application. This application schedules files. It was using Task Scheduler 1.0. But there were some problems that this was not able to perform its functionality completely in vista and seven. The solution is to move to Task Scheduler 2.0.

There was `ITask::EditWorkItem` in v1.0 which displayed a GUI in which user can select when to run the schedule. Problem is that I am unable to find this dialog in v2.0. There `ITaskDefinition` but this doesn't have `TaskEditDialog` or something like that.

How I can get that dialog?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That dialog is seemingly not available after vista was first patched. The only way seems to be that you have to make the GUI yourself and let the users to enter and edit there what you need them to enter and edit.

Comment: On different forums I found out that the only solution is making new dialogue. But that will take too much time.

Comment: Then refuse to write software. You can always choose a job that takes less of your precious time.

Comment: Öö Tiib, is right in s.w domain sometime you have no choice but to burn your own fuel! We daily come across such situations and we have to go for these and this is usually where we make money ;)

Answer (score 1):

Yes in case of 2.0 ITask::EditWorkItem is not present, i would suggest to take a look at http://taskscheduler.codeplex.com/ "This project provides a single assembly wrapper for the 1.0 and 2.0 versions of Task Scheduler found in all Microsoft operating systems post Windows 98. It simplifies the coding, aggregates the multiple versions, provides an editor and allows for localization support."

Comment: I saw this codeplex project. This is good but I cannot use third party.

Comment: And even they had made a new dialog of EditWorkItem.

Comment: Dear as far as i can see you got two options! 1) Write your own GUI 2) Or use some third party, Microsoft should hv make it backword compatible, but they didn't. So now its up to you, make your own GUI, and the reason why codeplex got new GUI, obviously clear. As Microsfot break backword compatibility, so they have to create their own!